# how to upgrade existing framework which installed using carthage

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode8, carthage

I have installed charts framework using carthage. Now need to update framework for swift 3 version.

> Carthage/Build/iOS/Charts.framework/Charts compiled with older version
>   of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0) for architecture
>   x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

How to upgrade framework?

Comment: In your Cartfile, tell it to get the Swift3 compatible version (V3) `github "danielgindi/Charts" ~> 3.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

There is a new release for Swift 3. You need to update your `Cartfile` to point to this version:

```
github "danielgindi/Charts" == 3.0.0
```

Then re-run `carthage update`.

Comment: I used this, but it shows The following dependencies are duplicates:
 github "danielgindi/Charts" (found in Cartfile)

Comment: Could you post your whole `Cartfile` please?

Comment: github "danielgindi/Charts" == 3.0.0
github "danielgindi/Charts" ~> 3.0.0 this is my cart file...

Comment: You only need one of those lines. The first one specifies exactly that version, the second species a compatible version (following semantic versioning rules). Just pick the one that applies to you and delete the other.

Comment: A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/
Carthage/Checkouts/Charts/Charts.xcodeproj CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES -list) failed with exit code 72:
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH

Comment: This is a separate issue. Carthage cannot find the `xcodebuild` tool. Check that you have it installed by running it manually. e.g.: `xcodebuild --version`. More information available here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

Comment: thanks for your help. Upgrade successfully done, some new version code issues only available i will fix it

Comment: No probs! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks!